# Click Event for Dynamic Divs not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created divs with Click Event based on a value entered in a text box.

[**An Example Here**](http://goo.gl/Clwcx)

When you open the page and click any of the rows, you will get an alert. But when you change the value in the text box (Enter Number) and hit load button, then the rows will load based on the number entered.

Now when you click any rows, the click event does not work.....

Any Help in this regard is highly appreciated..........

Comment: Showing the problematic JS code would be really helpful.

Comment: I think that HTML was supposed to be a link to the jsFiddle. Go to the link and you can see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.

```
$(".schoolselect").live("click", function() {
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/27Z3t/

Comment: Let me add that the same goes for the mouseenter event, just for precaution :)

Comment: I did notice the mouseover/mouseout events after posting the initial fiddle. I added live to both of those in the newest link.

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler for `$('.schoolselect')` is only attached once when the page loads. It is not a [live jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but that technique is deprecated in favour of the delegate model.

You can attach a delegate to `$('#divHSSchoolResultTable')` that will handle the clicks;

```
$('#divHSSchoolResultTable').delegate('.schoolselect', 'click', function() { alert(); });
```

See [jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for more details.

Comment: Actually "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation."

Comment: @Mario Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler.

Comment: Not that I'm disputing what you just said, but, why did the jQuery team decided to change the .delegate() method for the .on() method? (i'm actually curious)

Comment: @Mario in most situations using the .on() method is preferred. I find that I do a lot of dynamic insertions and it is simpler to create the one delegate than needing to attach the event handlers with on afterwards each time. It's probably just a style thing I've not run any performance tests.

Comment: The thing is, I also do a lot of dynamic insertions and the .on() method works like a charm (for me) and I was curious to know in what situation it doesn't, so I won't be spending a lot of time debugging when it breaks. (being that the .on method works very similarly to the .delegate())